# Install Material-UI in a private react component library (as an NPM package)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components, npm-package

I have tried installing `Material-UI` in a private `react` component library (NPM package) using typescript, customising some `MUI` components and then importing them inside another app from my own package.

The issue is that, it always throws an error inside the application saying:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

**Console error:**

[image]

**Styled MUI component inside the NPM package (private-component-library):**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { makeStyles, Checkbox, CheckboxProps } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& + .MuiFormControlLabel-label.Mui-disabled': {
      color: theme.palette.grey[400],
    },
  },
}))

export const StyledCheckbox: React.FC<CheckboxProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Checkbox
      className={classes.root}
      color='default'
      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'decorative checkbox' }}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}

export default StyledCheckbox
```

**This is how I am exporting components inside the package (`index.ts` file):**

```
export { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
export { Box } from '@material-ui/core'
export { StyledCheckbox } from './components/StyledCheckbox'
export theme from 'theme/theme'
```

**Importing the component inside application (`MyComponent.tsx` file):**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyledCheckbox } from 'private-component-library'

export const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (
     <Box pb={5}>
        <StyledCheckbox />
     </Box>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

**And the content of `App.tsx`**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'private-component-library'
import theme from 'private-component-library'

import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' children={<MyComponent />} />
        <Redirect
          from='/:url*(/+)'
          to={{ ...location, pathname: location.pathname.slice(0, -1) }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

**and `index.tsx` file of the application:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router basename='/home'>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

I tried removing `react` and `react-dom` dependencies from my private NPM package, or even adding them as `peerDependencies` or `devDependencies` and it didn't help.

I also tried the debugging steps of https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call and it also couldn't help the issue.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: general tips: react and react-dom must keep as dependencies, not dev or peer.

Comment: Can you put your package.json files of both package here?

Comment: are you sure the useStyles or useTheme are cause the problem? you can comment them and check this again.

Comment: @Afshin did you ever figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install this two plugins "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external", "rollup-plugin-terser" and follow the link aswell.`external: ["react", "react-dom", "@material-ui/core"],`
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-component-library-react-typescript/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).